# CSS: hidden mistake about menu hover

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have problem with my website's navigation. When I use to put logo image above the menu menu hover not working correctly. More clear: on menu hover background not working but border working. See examples:

Above:
[image]

With logo:

[image]

How I want to be:

[image]

CSS:

```
#simple-menu{display: block;float: right;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);padding: 15px 20px;-webkit-border-radius: 5px;-moz-border-radius: 5px;border-radius: 5px;margin-top: 1.5%;}
#simple-menu{ display:none;}
.pad_menutitle{padding: 5%;width: 90%;background: #2dcb73;}
.pad_menutitle span{display: inline-block;float: right; cursor:pointer;}


#topmenu{ float:left; padding-top:40px;}
#topmenu ul{ margin:0; padding:0;}
#topmenu ul li{ list-style-type:none; display:inline-block; margin-left:25px;padding-bottom: 28px;position: relative;}
#topmenu ul li a, #topmenu ul li ul li{-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;transition:all 0.2s ease-out;}

#topmenu ul li ul{ display:none;position: absolute;width: 200px;z-index: 9999999; margin-top:28px;margin-left:-50px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li{ margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; display:block; text-align:center;}
#topmenu ul li ul li a{ padding:10px 10%; width:80%; margin:0px; display:block;background:#333 url(images/submenu.png) repeat;}
#topmenu ul li ul li a:hover{ background:#2dcb73 url(images/trans_black_3.png) repeat;color:#fff!important;}
#topmenu ul li ul li a{ font-size:16px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li ul{left: 100%; margin-top:-40px; float:none; margin-left:0px;}

#topmenu ul li span{ font-size:12px; opacity:0.5; padding-left:5px;}
#topmenu ul li ul li span{ display:none;}
```

and

```
/*Headers4*/
.header4{width:100%; background:#1c6129; height:auto; float:left;}
.header4 a{ color:#fff;}
.header4 .center{ position:relative;}
.header4 .logoimga{ display:block; float:left;}

.header4 #topmenu{ margin-top:0;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li{padding: 0 20px 0 20px; padding-top:34px; padding-bottom:31px;border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;margin-left: -4px;-webkit-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-moz-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-ms-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;-o-transition:all 0.2s ease-out;transition:all 0.2s ease-out;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li ul li{ padding:0; margin-left:0; border-bottom:none; line-height:normal!important; height:auto!important;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li ul{top: 90px;margin-left: 0px; margin-top:0;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li ul li ul{ margin-top:-90px; margin-left:0;}
.header4 .current-menu-item{ background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);}
.header4 #topmenu ul li:hover{background:rgba(174, 215, 211, 0.2);border-bottom: 3px solid #2dcb73;}
.header4 #topmenu ul .zn_parent_menu:hover{border-bottom: 3px solid transparent!important;}
.header4 #topmenu .sub-menu{border-top: 3px solid #2dcb73;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li:hover ul li{ border-bottom:none;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header4">
    <div class="center">  
    <!--LOGO START-->     
    <div class="logo">

            <center><img src="logo.png"></center>

    </div>
    <!--LOGO END-->  

    <!--MENU START--> 
        <!--MOBILE MENU START--><a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"><i class="fa-align-justify"></i> <?php _e('Menu' , 'asteria'); ?></a><!--MOBILE MENU END--> 
    <div id="topmenu"><?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?></div>
    <!--MENU END-->

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please make a fiddle or attach link to your site.

Comment: This is the only way? because I working on virtual server (WAMP)

Comment: It would be better to look the situation in Firebug, at least for me. In this code with 3 screenshots I won´t find mistakes, sorry.

Comment: You should also be aware that `<center>` has been deprecated under HTML5 and should no longer be used.

Comment: I deleted <center> but it still does same

Comment: Open the page in your browser, view-source and copy + paste the headers HTML. Place the HTML [in this](http://jsfiddle.net/48xgj/) and then click "update" .

Comment: Finally I uploaded and there is the linkg: http://glpt.2gdmedia.com/

Comment: @misterManSam http://jsfiddle.net/48xgj/1/ there works great but not on my site, you can check with your own http://glpt.2gdmedia.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 47 of your style.css has:

```
body .header4 .bigmenu ul li:hover{ background:none!important; }
```

Move line 41 -

```
.header4 #topmenu ul li:hover{background:rgba(174, 215, 211, 0.2) !important;border-bottom: 3px solid #2dcb73;}
```

to underneath that line and **remove `!important`**

It should look like this

```
body .header4 .bigmenu ul li:hover{ background:none;}
.header4 #topmenu ul li:hover{background:rgba(174, 215, 211, 0.2);border-bottom: 3px solid #2dcb73;}
```

This is assuming that you still want to remove the hover background at all. If not, just remove line 47.

Answer (score 0):

Change `#topmenu{ float:left; padding-top:40px;}` to `#topmenu{ text-align:center; padding-top:40px;}` in your style.css.

And if you want to give active background like hover then just remove the css in your  style.css

```
.header4 .current-menu-item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

and add

```
.header4 .current-menu-item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(174, 215, 211, 0.2);
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2DCB73;
}
```

and for no effect on active element make `background:none;` in your style.css like

```
.header4 .current-menu-item {
        background: none;
    }
```

I have also checked the url http://glpt.2gdmedia.com/
where on line no 67 in style.css modify the .logo css to

```
.logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and on line 41 in style.css replace the code with

```
.header4 #topmenu ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(174, 215, 211, 0.2) !important;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #2DCB73;
}
```